# RShiny Error in showModal(ModalDialog(h3(...))): "Warning:Error in writeImpl: Text to be written must be length-one character vector"

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, interactive

I created this package called mingiPolygons. It identifies a polygon object in a map visualization formed by ggplot package. I have made it compatible with data in sf package. When creating a dashboard with a popup message I get this error, "Warning: Error in writeImpl: Text to be written must be length-one character vector".
This is the code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(reactable)
library(rsconnect)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(mingiPolygons)
library(shinyjs)

nameshp <- system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")
tableau <- read.csv('childcare modified.csv')

# GET DATA FROM NORTH CAROLINA COUNTY
nc_tab <- tableau %>%
  filter(state_name == "North Carolina")

dream <- st_read(nameshp, quiet=TRUE)
dream$vble <- dream$SID74
dream$vble2 <- dream$SID79

# merge datasets
d <- merge(x=dream, y=nc_tab, by.x = "FIPSNO", by.y="county_fips_code", all=TRUE)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(d)+
      geom_sf(aes(fill=vble))+
      scale_fill_distiller(palette="YlGnBu", direction=1)
  })
  
  d_reactive <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  tryCatch({
    observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
      d_reactive(d)
      kristy <- mingiPolygons:::preWork(d_reactive(), "NAME")
      county_choice <- mingiPolygons(kristy, input$plot_click, "NAME", 50, 4)
      sel_county_data <- d_reactive()[d_reactive()$NAME == as.character(county_choice),]
      
      if(!is.null(sel_county_data)){
        showModal(modalDialog(
          h3(as.character(sel_county_data[1, "NAME"]))
        ))
      } else if (is.null(sel_county_data)){
        showModal(ModalDialog(
          h2("The data is the problem. There is no information")
        ))
      }
    })
  })
  
  
}



ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
  tags$div(class="jumbotron text-center",
           style="margin-bottom:30px:margin-top:0px;height:10px;background-color: dodgerblue;color:ivory;font-size:30px",
           "New Sample"),
  fluidRow(column(12, plotOutput("plot", click='plot_click')))

)
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Some requirements:

1. Install mingiPolygons package: `devtools::install_github("mmburu8/mingiPolygons")`
   For  more information: https://mmburu8.github.io/mingiPolygons/
2. Download "childcare modified.csv": https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gl2CYv5mBJdV0Px45rokZzQwV66aVleU?usp=sharing

My main assumption is the data in variable "d", is used to evaluate polygon objects and contains information that is not being processed.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When subsetting an `sf` object, which has a `geometry` column, it is returned even if not selected explicitly. Thus, ìn your `h3` call you are **not** passing a string, but an `sf` object, which let `h3` issue the warning.

The remedy is easy: drop the `geometry` column explicitly:

```r
### [...]
h3(sel_county_data[1, "NAME", drop = TRUE])
## or
## h3(st_drop_geometry(sel_county_data)[1, "NAME"]))
```